# Visual studio shows "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" but program still executes normally?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.forms app and in visual studio i have the following error

*Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.*

The app executes normally in every way and no exception is thrown, but this error still persists in the errors tab. Is this actually a problem or should i ignore this?

Comment: That's odd.  Can you look at the stack trace or inner exception to see the line causing the error?

Comment: I couldn't find anything specific, however i found out that only in debug mode the app runs normally, and in release mode it breaks immidiatly when i press run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android options->advanced only enable x86 and x86_64 and disable the rest. This fixed the issue for me

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.